# Unexpected Response From Multipart Form POST to Google

Tags: .net, post, c++-cli, multipartform-data

So I'm working on a little app that currently POSTs a specified image from the hard disk to Google's reverse image search and processes a response. The problem is the response I'm getting is not what is expected. I've done as well as I could on my own to replicate the structure of the POST request, and I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm not getting the response I expect. I do get a 200 response code, but the HTML output is some sort of Google error (Search by image is unavailable. Please try again in a few hours). I've used Fiddler to figure out the structure of the request and from what I can tell, the one generated from my app is virtually identical aside from the lack of a Cookie header (could that be it?). If so, how would I go about creating a cookie and plugging it into my request?

[Here's the request made through Google's upload service.](http://justpaste.it/1i7v)

[Here's the request made through my app.](http://justpaste.it/1i7u)

Here's my code:
(Note: I'm sure it can be written far more eloquently and efficiently (e.g. using a StringBuilder), and I've hard-coded a lot of it, but it should be good enough for temporarily testing out the basic functionality)

```
    String^ url = "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload";
    HttpWebRequest^ request = (HttpWebRequest^) WebRequest::Create(url);
    request->Method = "POST";
    request->UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0";
    request->Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request->Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.5";
    request->Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
    String^ boundary = "-----------------------------23281168279961";
    request->ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    request->Referer = "https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi";

    String^ header = boundary + "\n";
    header += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_url\"\n\n\n";

    header += boundary + "\n";
    header += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"encoded_image\"; filename=\"2010-04-09-ec52529.png\"\n";
    header += "Content-Type: image/png\n\n";

    String^ footer = "\n" + boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_content\"\n\n\n";

    footer += boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"\n\n\n";

    footer += boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"num\"\n\n";
    footer += "10\n";

    footer += boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hl\"\n\n";
    footer += "en\n";

    footer += boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"safe\"\n\n";
    footer += "off\n";

    footer += boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bih\"\n\n";
    footer += "578\n";

    footer += boundary + "\n";
    footer += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"biw\"\n\n";
    footer += "1366\n";
    footer += boundary + "--\n";

    array<Byte>^ headerData = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(header);
    array<Byte>^ imageData = File::ReadAllBytes(oldImage);
    array<Byte>^ footerData = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(footer);

    request->ContentLength = headerData->Length + imageData->Length + footerData->Length;

    Stream^ reqStream = request->GetRequestStream();

    reqStream->Write(headerData, 0, headerData->Length);
    reqStream->Write(imageData, 0, imageData->Length);
    reqStream->Write(footerData, 0, footerData->Length);

    HttpWebResponse^ response = (HttpWebResponse^) request->GetResponse();
    StreamReader^ reader = gcnew StreamReader(response->GetResponseStream());
    String^ things = reader->ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: What's with your `Expect` header?

Comment: Hmm, good question. No idea why that's in there, I don't have that anywhere in my code.

Comment: Also, you have newlines separating your lines. It should be Internet standard line endings (`\r\n`).

Comment: I replaced every \n with \r\n; same result. I also figured out how to get rid of the Expect header from [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx), but again, same result.

Comment: Hi! Have you been able to do that? I tried to do the same using an headless browser, but i get the same error. In case, I'll add an answer if I find it

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani I believe I ended up solving the issue by including the cookie header.

Comment: I already tried that. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Google is a bit picky in handling the request headers. There are three problems I ran into:

- The image is encoded in base64, with `+` replaced with `-`, `/` replaced with `_`
- `Content-Type` boundary parameter must NOT be quoted
- `Content-Disposition` name parameters must be quoted

If you are using C#, here's a drop-in replacement for `MultipartFormDataContent` that handles these quirks, code adapted from [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/MultipartFormDataContent.cs):

```
public class MultipartFormDataContentCompat : MultipartContent
{
    public MultipartFormDataContentCompat() : base("form-data")
    {
        FixBoundaryParameter();
    }

    public MultipartFormDataContentCompat(string boundary) : base("form-data", boundary)
    {
        FixBoundaryParameter();
    }

    public override void Add(HttpContent content)
    {
        base.Add(content);
        AddContentDisposition(content, null, null);
    }

    public void Add(HttpContent content, string name)
    {
        base.Add(content);
        AddContentDisposition(content, name, null);
    }

    public void Add(HttpContent content, string name, string fileName)
    {
        base.Add(content);
        AddContentDisposition(content, name, fileName);
    }

    private void AddContentDisposition(HttpContent content, string name, string fileName)
    {
        var headers = content.Headers;
        if (headers.ContentDisposition != null)
            return;
        headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = QuoteString(name),
            FileName = QuoteString(fileName)
        };
    }

    private string QuoteString(string str)
    {
        return '"' + str + '"';
    }

    private void FixBoundaryParameter()
    {
        var boundary = Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Single(p => p.Name == "boundary");
        boundary.Value = boundary.Value.Trim('"');
    }
}
```

And to upload your image:

```
private static string FileToBase64(string imagePath)
{
    byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(content).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
    return base64;
}

public static void UploadImage(string imagePath)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var form = new MultipartFormDataContentCompat();
        form.Add(new StringContent(FileToBase64(imagePath)), "image_content");
        form.Add(new StringContent(Path.GetFileName(imagePath)), "filename");
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://images.google.com/searchbyimage/upload", form).Result;
        // Do whatever you want with the response
    }
}
```